# The media player ActiveX object in Internet Explorer plays only one video

Tags: internet-explorer, media-player

I have Java as the back-end. For videos I'm using the media player ActiveX object in Internet Explorer. When I open it the first time it plays OK. The file extention is ".ogg". But when it is opened the second time, it doesn't play any more.

The ActiveX object element is created as many times as the video look button is pressed and is destroyed after the user closes the modal window (*Ext.Window*).

Is there a solution?

Comment: Could you post the source code of the web page with the problem?